# Is there a best practice way to direct output of the development server to stdout for a front-end dev server?

Tags: django, django-dev-server

Let's say I have a a hybrid application (the django templater is required to serve the page with the form widgets, data, etc, however there is still a decent amount of js/ejs/lodash/etc wizardry going on in the front-end).

The front-end engineers would prefer to develop on `npm`'s purpose-built front-end dev server, but need the output from the django templater. What is the correct way to simulate a browser request, and direct the page body to `stdout` (to be picked up by `webpack` or whatever else is going on in the front-end dev environment)?

Should I `manage.py runserver`, and simulate a request with `curl`? Or is there a better way? It strikes me as difficult to manage authentication and csrf this way.

Comment: Just don't use django for the front end, just have it develop an api instead that your frontend can use

Comment: No, that's not a good solution. This isn't an SPA.